# A little bit of trouble computing the characteristic polynomial of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

I'm reading Smirnov's *Linear Algebra and Group Theory,* here:

> [image]

He says that is the characteristic equation but when I compute it on Mathematica, I obtained: $-(\lambda -2)^2 \left(\lambda ^3-27 \lambda -26\right)$. For reference, I computed it as follows:

> [image]

I think the different result may come from Mathematica computing it in some different number domain perhaps? Or this is some typo in the book?

Comment: I think there is a typo in the matrix, and I think he/she intended $$a_{41} = -4$$

Comment: @Moo:  I think you're right (+1).  How did you figure that out?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: I just assumed that a single value had a wrong sign and I started with the largest term and worked my way down until I found which one it was. I would try searching for the book errata to see if that is known.

Comment: @Moo I didn't find errata for this book but thank you very much!

Comment: Do the authors use the matrix in further calculations? That would really settle it.

Comment: @Moo Yes. This is from an example where the author is computing the Jordan normal form of that matrix. I'll try to compute it now.

Comment: @Moo There is a slight difference, the Jordan are quite similar but are inverted in order and there are some minor differences. See [here.](https://i.imgur.com/utynmGd.png)

Comment: Looks good to me, but you might want to ask another question on that because a Jordan canonical form is unique up to order of permutation.

Comment: @BillyRubina: Can you copy the entire page with that section / problem?

Comment: @Moo See [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AhuQPILCyRJwcAoWz7BERE8NGB9Nxq4d/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there is a typo in the matrix $A$ and the issue is that $a_{41}$ should be negative, so lets use this and find the Jordan canonical form. We have

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 
 -2 & -1 & -1 & 3 & 2 \\
 -4 & 1 & -1 & 3 & 2 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & -3 & -2 \\
 -4 & -2 & -1 & 5 & 1 \\
 4 & 1 & 1 & -3 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

The eigenvalues are $\lambda = 2$ (a triple root) and $\lambda_2 = -1$ (a double root).

This is a deficient matrix with some generalized eigenvectors.

We find

$$P = \begin{pmatrix}
 -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 & -2 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}, ~~~J = \begin{pmatrix}
 -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

This does not appear to match the authors results, but we can validate both.

Using the above, we verify

$$ A = P J P^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 
 -2 & -1 & -1 & 3 & 2 \\
 -4 & 1 & -1 & 3 & 2 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & -3 & -2 \\
 -4 & -2 & -1 & 5 & 1 \\
 4 & 1 & 1 & -3 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}~~~\Large\color{\green}{\unicode{10004}}$$

Using the authors' results, we can verify

$$A = V \Lambda V^{-1} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
 0 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & -2 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}~~~\Large\color{\green}{\unicode{10004}}$$

A couple of items to note:

$1.$ Eigenvectors are not unique.

$2.$ The Jordan canonical form is unique up to order of permutation.

So, these answers are equivalent and we have proven using the authors' calculations that indeed there is a typo in the book.